# Upload file using Python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem when writing REST API to upload files by Python.
This is the REST API on Postman. It worked.
[image]

But when I write the python code, it shows this error `<Response [400]>`.
Here is my code

```pyhton
import requests

headers = {
'X-Mobsf-Api-Key': '587b10a3f848a4e16ca8f6f0703dcfeaad2d7056f7b394534da0a6ad430f4739'
}

files = {
'file': open("C://Users//ASUS//anaconda3//phd_implement//productivity_categor//1clickVPN-1.1.3.apk", 'rb')
}

response = requests.post('http://193.206.183.20:8000/api/v1/upload', headers=headers, files=files)
print(response)
```

[image]

Note: I even test on Linux. It has the same error too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure the apk file can be accessed from where ever you're running?

Comment: @Kulasangar I have run the test on Ubuntu (and update question), and it also has the same error.

Comment: is it possible to get the full stack trace? cos 400 is simply a bad request, which means the request doesn't like something you're sending part of the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try separating out by opening the file first and then parsing it into the request:

```
test_file = open("1clickVPN-1.1.3.apk", "rb")

test_response = requests.post('http://193.206.183.20:8000/api/v1/upload', headers=headers, files = {"file": test_file})
```

Just for testing purpose, can you please place the apk file, in the location from wherever you're running the python script. If it works, then you can change.

Comment: It still has error. I think we need put "multipart/form-data" in the request.